# List images in HTML table using 'float: left'

Tags: html, css

I have a number of images of *very* differing height and width that I need to display in a web application's dialog box.

Putting the images into a table won't look good, as some very wide images will stretch the whole column, producing a ridiculous looking result.

Making all images `float: left` comes very close what I want to achieve: All images are next to each other, and when there is no space any more horizontally, the next image will move to the next row.

The problem is that this - moving to the next row - is not guaranteed due to the varying heights of the images. Usually, the remedy to this is `clear: both` but with `float: left` I can never know *when* I need to set `clear: both` because I do not know the pictures' widths.

THe only way around this that I can see is programmatically calculating each image's width (using PHP or Javascript), and when the horizontal space is full, injecting a `clear: both`. That is quite resource intensive, though, and I would love to be able to solve this without it.

**Is there any way to achieve this using pure CSS?**

Is my question clear enough and easy to understand?  If not please comment and I will clarify.

> **Edit:** Thanks for your input folks. Using `display: inline` on the images works fine. This adds a few other issues but in principle, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display:inline on the images will let them wrap around to the next line based on the container's fixed width

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? If a question, please post it as a comment.

Comment: display:inline renders each item side by side until the line wraps, whereas float:left positions each item to the left as far as possible.

So float:left can end up stacking items in the unused space on a line, whereas display:inline will wrap.

"In inline formatting context, boxes are laid out horizontally, one after the other. A line box is always tall enough for all of the boxes it contains."

Comment: @jspcal, you're right and I didn't get it. It works this way. Thanks!

Comment: definitely the layout behavior is a bit weird/unintuitive, even some things like which html doctype you're using can change the entire layout model elements like img use, causing all sorts of weirdness in addition to browser quirks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, you will have to use either server side scripting or client side scripting to solve this problem.

Comment: Your're probably right, I'll resort to doing this in PHP when I output the images. I'll leave this question open for a while in case somebody comes up with an unexpected CSS only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider forcing them to thumbnail formats of fixed width/height and add a link/onclick to show the full image in a dialog.

E.g.

```
<img src="img1.jpg" width="100" height="75" onclick="window.open('img1.jpg')">
<img src="img2.jpg" width="100" height="75" onclick="window.open('img2.jpg')">
<img src="img3.jpg" width="100" height="75" onclick="window.open('img3.jpg')">
...
```

You could even make use of [lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) to have a nice slide / auto-sized presentation.

Comment: Already considered and rejected in this case, the images are line drawings that react very badly to any resizing.

Comment: Well, than you're pretty stuck. Only other solution I can think of is just placing them in div's of fixed size with `overflow:scroll`. But I don't think you like to have scrollbars everywhere.